# How to recover edge passwords from SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I have my SSD from my broken PC, I bought an adapter so I can plug it into my new PC via usb-c. How would I go about recovering my passwords from edge on my old SSD?
Thanks

Comment: If you're using the same Microsoft account everything should be synced, not need to retrieve any info from the old drive.

Comment: Apart from ChanganAuto's comment, in the future you might want to consider using a password manager that is independent from the browser vendor - and make two or three of your own backups of the password database.

Comment: ChanganAuto, I am using the same account. How do I access the passwords? they are not appearing in edge

Answer (score -1):

I work in IT and the location of the Bookmarks/Passwords tend to save in this location:

`C:\users\'name'\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default` and you should see ***Bookmarks.bak*** files. There is also a section `..\User Data\Auto fill` - you may see the passwords within that.

But what I would do is copy the whole of the User Data folder and paste it in the same location for Edge on your new PC.

Comment: The author is trying to restore the passwords stored and managed by Chromium Edge, stored fields that might contain passwords, has no relevance to what the authors is attempting to do. It appears you vastly overestimated your understanding of the author’s question. Chromium Edge doesn’t store passwords in the bookmark database file